# MySQL bug - decimal comparison

Tags: mysql, floating-point, decimal

I'm currently writing unit tests for a stored procedure that calculates the amount of taxes and the tax rate based on the country/province the customer lives in.

Somehow, MySQL considers that "*14.975*" is different than "*14.975*".

[image]

If I try `taxRate < 14.975` or `taxRate = 14.975`, it does not enter the condition; but `taxRate <> 14.975` and `taxRate > 14.975` does.

I have the feeling I'm missing something obvious, but I just can't figure it out.

**My test code**:

```
  DECLARE totalTax DECIMAL(20,6) DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE taxRate DECIMAL(10,3) DEFAULT 0;

  SET @roundMode = 0;
  SET @roundPrecision = 2;

  /* caculate TPS only*/

  CALL calculateTotalTaxOnAmount (200, 4, NULL, totalTax, taxRate);

  IF (totalTax <> 10) THEN

    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
      SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'INVALID_TAX_AMOUNT_CANADA';
  ELSEIF (taxRate <> 5) THEN

    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
      SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'INVALID_TAX_RATE_CANADA';
  END IF;

  /* caculate TPS and TVQ */

  CALL calculateTotalTaxOnAmount (100, 4, 87, totalTax, taxRate);

  IF (totalTax <> 14.98) THEN

    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
      SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'INVALID_TAX_AMOUNT_CANADA_QUEBEC';
  ELSEIF (taxRate <> 14.975) THEN

    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
      SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'INVALID_TAX_RATE_CANADA_QUEBEC';
  END IF;
```

**My function**:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE calculateTotalTaxOnAmount (
    IN amount DECIMAL(20,6),
    IN countryID INT(10),
    IN stateID INT(10),
    OUT totalTax DECIMAL(20,6),
    OUT totalTaxRate DECIMAL(10,3) 
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE break BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE taxBehavior INT(10);
    DECLARE taxRate DECIMAL(10,3);

    DECLARE TaxCursor CURSOR FOR
        SELECT (t.`rate` / 100),
            tr.`behavior`
        FROM `ps_tax_rule` tr 
        JOIN `ps_tax` t
            ON tr.`id_tax` = t.`id_tax`
        WHERE tr.`id_country` = countryID 
        AND tr.`id_state` IN (0, stateID) 
        AND t.`active` = 1
        ORDER BY tr.`id_state`;

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET break = TRUE;

    SET totalTax = 0;
    SET totalTaxRate = 0;

    OPEN TaxCursor;

    tax_loop: LOOP
        FETCH TaxCursor INTO 
            taxRate,
            taxBehavior;

        IF (break) THEN

            LEAVE tax_loop;
        END IF;

        IF (taxBehavior = 2) THEN /* cumulative tax */

            SET totalTax = totalTax + (amount + totalTax) * taxRate;

        ELSE /* standalone tax */

            SET totalTax = totalTax + (amount * taxRate);
        END IF;
    END LOOP tax_loop;

    CLOSE TaxCursor;

    IF (totalTax <> 0) THEN

        SET totalTaxRate = totalTax * 100 / amount;

        SET totalTax = roundMoney(totalTax);
    END IF;
END //
```

**Note**: If you want to test it locally, replace `roundMoney(totalTax)` by `round(totalTax, 2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made some tests and manage to find some interesting results.

1. You can use the casting operation to solve the problem:

   `SET totalTaxRate = CAST(totalTax * 100 / amount AS DECIMAL(10,3));`
2. You can use the truncate operation to solve the problem:

   `SET totalTaxRate = TRUNCATE(totalTax * 100 / amount, 3);`
3. Somehow, using a select after changing the value of the variable seems to also solve the problem...

   `SET totalTaxRate = totalTax * 100 / amount;
   SELECT totalTaxRate;`

   I'd rather not use this solution as it returns a recordset.
4. Using a select into also solve the problem

   `SELECT totalTax * 100 / amount INTO totalTaxRate;`

**Note**: You can use the truncate or casting operation either inside or outside the procedure (even both), but I'd suggest to do it inside so you don't have use the truncate/casting operation on the output every time you call the procedure.

I still can't assert for sure the root of the problem but, at least, there are some ways to work around it.

Comment: The root of the problem is floating point arithmetic. Necessary read: **[What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://floating-point-gui.de/)**

Comment: Ok, but ain't the `DECIMAL` supposed to be the reliable way to store money?  "*These types are used when it is important to preserve exact precision, for example with monetary data.*" http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fixed-point-types.html

Comment: Yes, but you also have literals like `ELSEIF (taxRate <> 14.975) THEN` which I think have `float` type.

Comment: @JonathanParentLévesque If you want to edit your answer to include ypercube's comment & mark this as an answer, you can close out the question!